# Swift: NSBezier

Tags: swift, macos, drawing, nsview, nsbezierpath

This is the code inside my custom view class:

```
func drawTestingPoint(_ point: CGPoint, target: Int, output: Int) {
    let path = NSBezierPath()
    path.appendArc(withCenter: point, radius: 5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360)
    NSColor.black.setStroke()
    if target == output {
        NSColor.green.setFill()
    } else {
        NSColor.red.setFill()
    }
    path.lineWidth = 3
    path.fill()
    path.stroke()
}

override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    //If I call the drawTestingPoint function here it works
}
```

Inside my `viewDidLoad` method in my `NSViewController` class I set up the custom view and try to draw the testing point:

```
let size = getDataViewSize()
let origin = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width/2-size.width/2, y: view.frame.height/2-size.height/2)
dataView = DataView(frame: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
view.addSubview(dataView)
dataView.drawTestingPoint(CGPoint(x: view.frame.width/2 y: view.frame.height/2), target: target, output: output)
dataView.needsDisplay = true
```

My problem is that no point is getting drawn. I think there can't be anything wrong with my `drawTestingPoint` function because when I call it inside my `draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)` function in my custom `NSView` class, it works. What can I do so I can call this function inside my `viewDidLoad` function how you can see in the codes snippets above so my point gets drawn

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't clear.  First, nobody knows what DataView is.  Assuming that it's a subclass of NSView, one still doesn't know if it's an existing NSView object that is connected to a view controller.

Comment: I've already been drawing sth. on my custom NSView so that is not the problem. Yes your assumptions were right. I am trying to draw on my custom NSView after adding it to my view controllers view

Answer (score 1):

You can't just draw any time you want. Normally you set up a view and implement `draw(_:)` as you've done. The system calls the draw method when it needs the view to draw its contents. Before calling your `draw(_:)` method it sets up the drawing context correctly to draw inside your view and clip if you draw outside of the view. That's the bit you're missing.

As a general rule you should NOT draw outside of the view's `draw(_:)` method. I've done drawing outside of the `draw(_:)` method so infrequently that I don't remember what you'd need to do to set up the drawing context correctly. (To be fair I do mostly iOS development these days and my MacOS is getting rusty.)

So the short answer is "Don't do that."

### EDIT:

Instead, set up your custom view to save the information it needs to draw itself. As others have suggested, when you make changes to the view, set `needsDisplay=true` on the view. That will cause the system to call the view's `draw(_:)` method on the next pass through the event loop

Comment: so what would you recommend to do when you want to draw something in a NSView afterwards?

Comment: Set `view.needsDisplay = true`. AppKit will call your view's `drawRect:` method during the next display update pass.

Comment: i did call `dataView.needsDisplay = true` (last line in my code snippets)

Comment: You  need  to save  off the parameters you want to send to `drawTestingPoint()` and then pass them to `drawTestingPoint()` from `drawRect()`.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I would suggest having the view save it's own stat information rather than having `draw(_:)` pass parameters to `drawTestingPoint()` as @user1118321 suggests above.